# Trying to use the correct onclick events to make code run at different intervals

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, settimeout

I have 12 boxes I need to have turn on one after another after I press the 'MOVE' button in Javascript. The CSS and HTML I already have written for the program.

[image: The boxes I need to make light up 1 at a time]

This is the code I've written so far to turn on each box individually, but I need them all to turn on automatically and consecutively after 1 second with a single click of a button.

```
    on = () => {
        const element = document.getElementById('s1');
        element.classList.toggle('on');
    }
    let timer = null;
    start = () => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            toggle();
            start();
        }, 1000);
    }
    stop = () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
```

Comment: this `setTimeout(() => { }` ... does NOTHING - what did you expect it to do?

Comment: I added the code I had, must have deleted it when I was trying different things